# GitHub Actions for Automatic Tag Not Working

Tags: github-actions

One of my GitHub Actions for automatic tagging is not working and I don't seem to know why.

Here is my `tag.yml`:

```yaml
name: 'tag'
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  tag:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: 'Checkout'
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.4.0
      - name: 'Tag'
        uses: anothrNick/github-tag-action@1.36.0
        with:
          repo-token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
```

The error I get is this:

```sh
Warning: Unexpected input(s) 'repo-token', valid inputs are ['entryPoint', 'args']
Run anothrNick/github-tag-action@1.36.0
/usr/bin/docker run --name a72c5b92e429db40e09e9b93f3e458fdb9_f74ce8 --label 9916a7 --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e INPUT_REPO-TOKEN -e HOME -e GITHUB_JOB -e GITHUB_REF -e GITHUB_SHA -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER -e GITHUB_RUN_ID -e GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER -e GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS -e GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT -e GITHUB_ACTOR -e GITHUB_WORKFLOW -e GITHUB_HEAD_REF -e GITHUB_BASE_REF -e GITHUB_EVENT_NAME -e GITHUB_SERVER_URL -e GITHUB_API_URL -e GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL -e GITHUB_REF_NAME -e GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED -e GITHUB_REF_TYPE -e GITHUB_WORKSPACE -e GITHUB_ACTION -e GITHUB_EVENT_PATH -e GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_ACTION_REF -e GITHUB_PATH -e GITHUB_ENV -e RUNNER_OS -e RUNNER_ARCH -e RUNNER_NAME -e RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE -e RUNNER_TEMP -e RUNNER_WORKSPACE -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN -e ACTIONS_CACHE_URL -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/terraform-provider-mirantis/terraform-provider-mirantis":"/github/workspace" 9916a7:2c5b92e429db40e09e9b93f3e458fdb9
*** CONFIGURATION ***
    DEFAULT_BUMP: minor
    WITH_V: false
    RELEASE_BRANCHES: master,main
    CUSTOM_TAG: 
    SOURCE: .
    DRY_RUN: false
    INITIAL_VERSION: 0.0.0
    TAG_CONTEXT: repo
    PRERELEASE_SUFFIX: beta
    VERBOSE: true
Is master a match for main
Is main a match for main
pre_release = false
From https://github.com/Richard-Barrett/terraform-provider-mirantis
 * [new tag]         v1.0-beta  -> v1.0-beta
fatal: ambiguous argument '0.0.0': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
Merge pull request #14 from Richard-Barrett/Richard-Barrett-patch6 automating terraform with release and goreleaser
minor
Bumping tag 0.0.0. 
    New tag 0.1.0
2022-01-16T04:39:36Z: **pushing tag 0.1.0 to repo Richard-Barrett/terraform-provider-mirantis
  "message": "Bad credentials",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest"
}
Error: Tag was not created properly.
```

Here is the public Repo it is affiliated with: https://github.com/Richard-Barrett/terraform-provider-mirantis

Any advice...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missusing this action, it should be:

```
- name: 'Tag'
  uses: anothrNick/github-tag-action@1.36.0
  env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

All parameters are passed by ENV as described [here](https://github.com/anothrNick/github-tag-action#options)